# Swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when comparing implicitly unwrapped optional with nil

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have the following code

```
  func detachPlayer() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
      if self.playerView.player != nil {
        self.playerView.player.pause()
        self.playerView.player = nil
      }
    }
  }
```

`player` is defined as implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`), therefore, I've added a test for nil to avoid crash.
However, I am still getting a crash sometimes on this line:
`if self.playerView.player != nil`, which is confusing, as the control should just skip the part of code in braces if `player` is `nil`.

What really confuses me is that the only `nil` here is `player`. Everything else is initialized correctly:

```
(lldb) po self
<AppName.UICollectionViewCellSubclass: 0x15de630b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (59.7065 2467.02; 200.587 137.143); layer = <CALayer: 0x17003bf60>>


(lldb) po self.playerView
<VIMVideoPlayerView: 0x15de5f970; frame = (0 0; 200.587 137.143); layer = <AVPlayerLayer: 0x1700362c0>>


(lldb) po self.playerView.player
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Is there any explanation for such behavior?

Comment: Are you updating the UI off the main thread?

Comment: @Adrian even if I assume that I do, why does the crash happens on the very first line (nil-check)? The crash is hardly reproducible, and, moving operation to main thread seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. I also thought the async part was the reason for the crash. However my question is more about why does the debugger shows me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the nil-check line? Do you have any thoughts? Thanks.